# How can I fix forbidden 403 error I get using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook, tweepy, tweets

I am trying to extract tweets that include a specific hashtag(#nike) and I have essential level access(Twitter developer account). I only want to collect 100 tweets. Help, please! Thank you!
I keep getting this error:

Forbidden                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

````
     import tweepy

# function to display data of each tweet
def printtweetdata(n, ith_tweet):
        print()
        print(f"Tweet {n}:")
        print(f"Username:{ith_tweet[0]}")
        print(f"Description:{ith_tweet[1]}")
        print(f"Location:{ith_tweet[2]}")
        print(f"Following Count:{ith_tweet[3]}")
        print(f"Follower Count:{ith_tweet[4]}")
        print(f"Total Tweets:{ith_tweet[5]}")
        print(f"Retweet Count:{ith_tweet[6]}")
        print(f"Tweet Text:{ith_tweet[7]}")
        print(f"Hashtags Used:{ith_tweet[8]}")


# function to perform data extraction
def scrape(words, date_since, numtweet):

        # Creating DataFrame using pandas
        db = pd.DataFrame(columns=['username',
                                'description',
                                'location',
                                'following',
                                'followers',
                                'totaltweets',
                                'retweetcount',
                                'text',
                                'hashtags'])

        # We are using .Cursor() to search
        # through twitter for the required tweets.
        # The number of tweets can be
        # restricted using .items(number of tweets)
        tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
                            words, lang="en",
                            since_id=date_since,
                            tweet_mode='extended').items(numtweet)


        # .Cursor() returns an iterable object. Each item in
        # the iterator has various attributes
        # that you can access to
        # get information about each tweet
        list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]

        # Counter to maintain Tweet Count
        i = 1

        # we will iterate over each tweet in the
        # list for extracting information about each tweet
        for tweet in list_tweets:
                username = tweet.user.screen_name
                description = tweet.user.description
                location = tweet.user.location
                following = tweet.user.friends_count
                followers = tweet.user.followers_count
                totaltweets = tweet.user.statuses_count
                retweetcount = tweet.retweet_count
                hashtags = tweet.entities['hashtags']

                # Retweets can be distinguished by
                # a retweeted_status attribute,
                # in case it is an invalid reference,
                # except block will be executed
                try:
                        text = tweet.retweeted_status.full_text
                except AttributeError:
                        text = tweet.full_text
                hashtext = list()
                for j in range(0, len(hashtags)):
                        hashtext.append(hashtags[j]['text'])

                # Here we are appending all the
                # extracted information in the DataFrame
                ith_tweet = [username, description,
                            location, following,
                            followers, totaltweets,
                            retweetcount, text, hashtext]
                db.loc[len(db)] = ith_tweet

                # Function call to print tweet data on screen
                printtweetdata(i, ith_tweet)
                i = i+1
        filename = 'scraped_tweets.csv'

        # we will save our database as a CSV file.
        db.to_csv(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':

        # Enter your own credentials obtained
        # from your developer account
        consumer_key = ""
        consumer_secret = ""
        access_key = ""
        access_secret = ""


        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        # Enter Hashtag and initial date
        print("#nike")
        words = input("#nike")
        print("2022-01-01")
        date_since = input("2022-01-01")

        # number of tweets you want to extract in one run
        numtweet = 10
        scrape(words, date_since, numtweet)
        print('Scraping has completed!')```
````

Comment: You will need to use the v2 API features in Tweepy (since you have essential access which provides v2 access). Look at [`tweepy.client`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html) in the docs (instead of `tweepy.API`)